# How do I fix "startActivity() in ContextCompat cannot be applied to?"

Tags: java, android, android-intent, google-cloud-vision

I am using Google Vision OCR to grab the email from a business card (the OCR Graphic activity) and send it to the the To destination in the SendEmail activity. My log shows that the email text is detected.

I tried to set the intent to send it to the next activity, but I am getting two errors, "cannot resolve constructor Intent" on my new intent, and start activity cannot be applied to.

This is the OcrGraphic activity

```java
List<Line> lines = (List<Line>) text.getComponents();
        for(Line elements : lines) {
            float left = translateX(elements.getBoundingBox().left);
            float bottom = translateY(elements.getBoundingBox().bottom);
            if (elements != null && elements.getValue() != null) {


                if (elements.getValue().matches("^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\\\+]+(\\\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@\"\n" +
                        "\t\t+ \"[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$") || elements.getValue().contains("@")) {
                    Log.e("elementsemail", elements.getValue());
                    String email;
                    email = elements.getValue();
                    cEmail = email;
                    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(this, SendEmail.class);
                    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, cEmail);
                    startActivity(sendIntent);


                }
```

this is my Send Email activity

```java
private void sendMail(){

        Intent getIntent = getIntent();
        String recipientList = getIntent.getStringExtra(OcrGraphic.cEmail);;
        String[] recipients = recipientList.split(",");
        String subject = mEditTextSubject.getText().toString();
        String message = mEditTextMessage.getText().toString();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
        intent.setType("message/rfc822");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose an email client"));
    }
```

I want to send the email address to the SendEmail activity. I am new to java and android, any help is welcomed.

Comment: I guess u can have a method(Which should have the navigation logic) in the activity, call that method from this place.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're problem is how you obtain the extra(EXTRA_EMAIL)
Replace `String recipientList = getIntent.getStringExtra(OcrGraphic.cEmail);;` with `String recipientList = getIntent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL);`

Answer (score 0):

please replace this :

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(this, SendEmail.class);
```

whit this :

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SendEmail.class);
```

**edit**

You need to pass context in a constructor like this

```
private Context context;



OcrGraphic(GraphicOverlay overlay, TextBlock text, Context context) { 
       super(overlay); 
       this.context = context; 
       }
```

And then

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(context, SendEmail.class);
```

Comment: From that I got the error "Cannot resolve getApplicationContext". Do I need to import a library?

Comment: No getApplicationContext() is a method within activity class , so try with OcrGraphic.this since you are in OcrGraphic Activity

Comment: Can you tell my what class do you extend in your activity ?

Comment: GraphicOverlay.Graphic

Comment: Please check my edit , now it will work ,Since GraphicOverlay.Graphic is not a View you can not directly use getApplicationContext().